# Invert the legend scale representation [in R environment]

Tags: r, legend, scale, plot

Through the following code,

`cols <- (heat.colors(255))
plot(raster_sum3, col=cols[round(seq(1,255,length.out=10))], legend=TRUE) # raster of the study area
plot(site_3003, add=TRUE) # site boundaries`

I plot a raster obtaining the attached image[image]

I want to reverse the legend scale, in order to place lower values above and higher values in the bottom of the scale. Despite several researches, I did not find the appropriate syntax to reach my aim.

Comment: Can't easily done with the `plot` function for a raster. That function has the order of the legend hard coded in.